# Making an iOS app in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a completely empty single view application targeting iOS 5.1 and I am attempting to get the app to work only in landscape mode.

In the project summary screen I have selected both landscape options and I have deselected portrait options.

I verified in the info.plist that only landscape orientations appear.

In the storyboard I selected the view controller went to simulated metrics and selected landscape for the orientation.

When the app initially opens a black screen is displayed in landscape mode. When the plain white view is displayed it is in portrait mode. I have read through a number of posts and haven't been able to find a solution to this problem.

I feel like I am overlooking something simple but in the past when I wanted to make an app in landscape mode I just selected landscape in summary and it worked.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Can we see the code for your view controller?

Comment: What version of xcode are you using? I know you can code it, but if you use 4.5 then AutoLayout will take care of it for you.

Comment: Xcode version 4.5.2
In all of my previous projects Xcode took care of it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the following function implemented in your root view controller?

```
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    }
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Comment: I just added the code and nothing changed. I have added similar code from other posts as well and nothing changed.

Comment: Your root view and any other view have to agree on orientation. It sounds like your root is set correctly and your white screen isn't.

Comment: That link helps I was looking at code for 6.0 previously. Using the code in that link I was able to get it working in 5.1. Thanks!!!

Comment: why not use UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape so it will autorotate right and left?